# Nested complexTypes in XSD returning error: Element content is not allowed, because the type definition is simple

Tags: xml, xsd, complextype

I'm building an xml schema for this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<groups xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="basic.xsd">
<!--Comienza la descripción de los grupos sencillos-->
    <!--modificador-->
    <group tagName="A">
      <name>modificador</name>
      <type>simple</type>
      <words>
        <word>el<word>
        <word>este<word>
      </words>
    </group>
    <!--prefijos-->
    <group tagName="C">
      <name>prefijos</name>
      <type>simple</type>
      <words>
        <word>pre</word>
        <word>ante</word>
        <word>anti</word>
        <word>pro</word>
        <word>tri</word>
      </words>
    </group>
    <!--Composiciones de intérvalos-->
</groups>
```

And this is my xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!-- definition of simple elements -->
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="word" type="xs:string"/> 

<!-- definition of attributes -->
<xs:attribute name="tagName" type="xs:ID"/>

<!-- definition of complex elements -->
<xs:element name="words">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="word" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="group">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="name"/>
      <xs:element ref="type"/>
      <xs:element ref="words" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute ref="tagName" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="groups">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="group" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm using nokogiri to validate my xml, but I'm getting the following error:

> Element 'word': Element content is not allowed, because the type definition is simple.
>   XML not schema valid

Why should word be complex then? And how do I do that because to me it's just fine.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally used opening tags instead of closing tags at

```
<word>el<word>
<word>este<word>
```

in your input XML file. Since there are no closing tags, your XML is not well-formed. It's a good idea to always check well-formedness first.

You get the message "element content is not allowed" because it looks like there are `word` elements within `word` elements. This is only possible with complex types.

Change the affected lines in the input file to

```
<word>el</word>
<word>este</word>
```

and validation against your schema will succeed.

Comment: xD Gees, that was the problem, thanks... this was driving me crazy.